# Check matrix size

Tags: r

I'd like to check that a matrix's dimensions are specifically 3x3. I can do this by:

```
m <- matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
ifelse(dim(m)[1] == 3 & dim(m)[2] == 3, "size match!", "no match")
```

Here I have two comparisons, checking the row number and the column number. Is there are way to check this in a single test? Something that would syntactically appear as a single binary operator, like this: `dim(m) == c(3,3)` (this doesn't work).

Comment: `all(dim(m) == c(3,3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track... `all` might work..

```
> all(dim(m)==c(3,3))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or alternatively `all(dim(m) == 3)`

Comment: but, if the vectors are different lengths this won't work as expected

Answer (score 3):

You can use `all.equal`

```
> all.equal(dim(m), c(3,3))
[1] TRUE
```